# Top row (Function Keys) and Delete key not working on MacBook pro 13 inch Mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Recently, I got my MacBook Pro Mid-2012 13-inch Keyboard replaced. Initially, it was working perfectly. All of sudden (while typing), I noticed that my **Delete** Key stop working. Then I started checking other keys also and go to know that my **Volume** keys are behaving differently. I mean when I press them they do work correctly, but they don't do the stock commands like turning the volume up, down, brightness, next song, etc. I came to know about the **Keyboard Viewer** and to my surprise, I saw that the **fn** key is pressed by default. As far as I remember, I never pressed the **fn** key. Tried lots of solutions like resetting NVRAM, and the checkbox under the **System preferences -> Keyboard**. I don't know what is the exact issue. Sharing the link for the Image and Video reference.

https://we.tl/t-zMJwnUgYrY

[image]

Comment: If tapping Fn repeatedly doesn't free it, I'd just take it back to whoever 'fixed' it.